# Having gitlab produce installers

Tags: git, version-control, continuous-integration, gitlab

I set up a gitlab community instance with runners and CI and it's working great. The problem I'm facing right now is:

- Project EXE is the main executable
- Project DLL is the dependent DLL that EXE needs

I can build EXE and DLL independently with Gitlab runners but is there any way to have Gitlab

1. Build DLL
2. Build EXE
3. Pack them together (it would be **great** if I could have InnoSetup or some other kind of installer-creator to spit out a full-blown installer as artifact)

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `git submodules` is probably the way to go here. This way you are able to maintain two seperate projects while one project depends on the other. The neat effect here is that the CI pulls your EXE project, you are able to pull submodules with `git submodule update --recursive --remote`. Then you can first build your DLL (it now already resides in your EXE project) and then build your EXE.

A sample `.gitlab-ci.yml` could look something like this:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy

buildjob:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - git submodules update --recusive --remote
    - <build DLL>
    - <build EXE>
    - <create installer>
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - <path to installer>
```